# How to clean and rebuild classes in JCreator?

Tags: java, jcreator

Every time I change my code I get outdated output, so I have to delete all .class files and run the project again to refresh the output.

Comment: Why are you using JCreator ?

Comment: It's a pre-coded project and I try to change it.I can't run it with eclipse or netbeans.

Comment: You can run. Using Eclipse or Netbeans is not difficult. Try to learn for your future experiment and do not waste your time in JCreator.

Comment: I'm a netbeans user! I try a lot but it can't run this project.just a lot of errors..I even try to use Eclipse